# you haven't created a /boot/efi partition

Tags: centos, partition, uefi, scientific-linux

I am installing scientific linux 6.9  (based on redhat 6) on my surface book  . I created 4 partition :

```
88500MB / ext4
500MB /boot/efi EFI system partitioning
250MB /boot ext4
200MB swap
```

But when i click next i got the error  : you haven't created /boot/efi partition. How can i solve this problem  ?

Comment: The ESP (EFI System Partition) should be a small FAT32 formatted partition preferably at the very beginning of the drive (`/EFI`, not `/boot/efi`). With manula partitioning make sure to select all required partitions including the ESP. The3 installer will do everything else for you.

Comment: @ MichaelBay tanks alot. but I didn't understand . You mean I wrote /EFI instead of /boot/efi. May you give more explanation?

Comment: I meant you need `/EFI`, *a small FAT32 formatted partition preferably at the very beginning of the drive*

Answer (score 1):

As MichaelBay mentioned, your EFI partition needs to be formatted with FAT32. However, I understand that the way it's mounted can be confusing. Especially since it can be distro-specific.

According to RedHat's [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/s2-grub-whatis-booting-uefi), the EFI filesystem should be mounted at `/boot/efi/EFI`. This means that:

1. You need a FAT32-formatted partition of type EF00.
2. The partition must be configured to be mounted at `/boot/efi`
3. The filesystem in the partition must have an `EFI` directory.

In other words, your root filesystem will contain the directory `/boot/efi`, your ESP partition will contain the directory `EFI`, and the ESP partition will be mounted at `/boot/efi`, resulting in the path `/boot/efi/EFI`.

You can use the following layout in the installer:

```
88500MB / ext4
500MB /boot/efi fat32, but make sure the partition type is ESP/FE00.
200MB swap
```